# Share screenshot from internal storage android

Tags: android, share, android-internal-storage

I want to share the screenshot that gets stored in internal storage but all I'm getting while sharing is a blank screen. I came to know that another app cannot use ones won app private data. This is the code I have used to save the image :

```
File path = new File(getApplicationContext().getDir("Default", Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING),"myapp");
File directory = new File(path.getAbsolutePath());
directory.mkdirs();
String filename = "myapp.png";
File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
try
{
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, true);
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,out);
 out.flush();
 out.close();
 send(yourFile);
}catch (IOException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the share intent is:

```
public void send(File path)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(path);
    Log.d("uri", String.valueOf(path));
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My App");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

The path in which the image is getting saved and the value of path is :

> /data/user/0/com.sample.myapp/app_Default/myapp/myapp.png

Now how would I make sure that the screenshot is getting accessed and made available for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by exporting the image to external storage and then sharing.

```
 String url = null;
    try {
        url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), path.getAbsolutePath(), path.getName(), path.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting image URI not  Real Image path

to get Real path check this

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

just pass this image uri and get full image path

Comment: I have implemented your code and have edited my code above. Now when I run the code the app is getting crashed. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: what is the Exception?

Comment: This is what I'm getting " java.lang.NullPointerException : Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference"